# Getting random "facebookErrDomain error 10000"

Tags: ios, facebook-ios-sdk

I am using the latest facebook IOS SDK, and I am getting random `"facebookErrDomain error 10000"`, when using the `requestWithGraphPath`. I can trigger the request from the UI and sometimes it runs fine, sometimes it gives me the error.

Has anyone ran into a similar issue?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem was due to the fact that during the development I had changed the permissions requested by the application. I had authorized my application say with permission x,y,z but I was only asking for x,y.

What I had to do is to remove the application from the list of authorized applications and authorize it again with the appropriate permissions.

I wish they gave better error message :)

Comment: For example, for myself I had changed the posting URL from `feed` to `photos`. Once I flipped it back the problem was solved.

Answer (score 24):

The error object returned has the details about what's happening.
I suggest to implement that method to get more infos:

```
- (void)request:(FBRequest *)request didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
    NSLog(@"Err details: %@", [error description]);
};
```

For example for my problem gived me that info, and I've fixed it:

```
2011-05-27 11:19:57.313 Challengein[7704:207] The operation couldn’t be completed. (facebookErrDomain error 10000.)
2011-05-27 11:19:57.314 Challengein[7704:207] Err details: Error Domain=facebookErrDomain Code=10000 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (facebookErrDomain error 10000.)" UserInfo=0x6878b90 {error=<CFBasicHash 0x6879be0 [0x141c400]>{type = mutable dict, count = 2,
entries =>
    2 : <CFString 0x6877f70 [0x141c400]>{contents = "type"} = <CFString 0x686f9a0 [0x141c400]>{contents = "OAuthException"}
    3 : <CFString 0x686d610 [0x141c400]>{contents = "message"} = <CFString 0x686f970 [0x141c400]>{contents = "(#100) picture URL is not properly formatted"}
}
}
```

Comment: thanks for the tip, didn't realized that the description method gave a more detailed info of the problem.

Comment: You could also use [error userInfo] for a better log. It will print the userInfo dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

If that didnt work, look at the issues on GitHub
https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/issues/closed#issue/205

In the plist file under URL types, make sure you set  the value of "Item 0" to  "fb123456" instead of "fb[123456]"

that's what messed me up

Answer (score 0):

Check for the additional `error_msg` of your error. I expect it to be an "`OAuthException`" and an invalid/expired access_token. You need to provide a new access_token in case you got this error.

Comment: the error was an oauthexception but it wouldn't happen all the time: a new token would fail, then work, then fail.

Comment: please post complete error message in case you still need help

Comment: OAuth Exception and An active access token must be used to query information about the current user... these are the two i Got. HELP!!!!!!